# Swift / Xcode strange behaviour: "Use of undeclared type" error shown in case of struct used before declaration

Tags: swift, xcode

At the moment I see strange behaviour of Xcode **on swift project** and on playground

[image]

but this like works:

[image]

Can somebody explain what is the reason of this?

reproduced in playground **and swift 5.1 project**

Comment: Which version of Xcode?

Comment: latest. Version 11.3 (11C29)

Comment: But now I think that there is sth wrong with project where I have reproduced it...

Comment: No, I've just got another mind... you have variable declaration in global namespace, in this case order of declaration matters.

Comment: @Asperi you was right :) Thanks a lot

Comment: @Asperi please, post it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In screen 1 `settingsDb` variable is declared in global namespace, in this case order of declaration matters, so all types of top-level declarations must be declared before usage.

If one needs more details, look for "swift top-level", official developer.apple.com blog on this is [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7)

Answer (score 1):

## Playground

Order matters in Playground, because of progressive compile (or any other name it has). Playground tries to compile small chunk of codes, even line by line (if it could), and only recompile them if you touch it. But when it needs to recompile, it will recompile from the touch point the the end (automatically) or to the run point (manually). So the definition should be above. So lower parts can use it.

## General

Also all items with the same scope should be declared in order. It's same in the Xcode project too. In the playground we usually declare everything in global scope (like your code). but it's not related to playground and it will be happen in Xcode projects to.

Comment: so reproduce in my project is related to some problems with project... right?

Comment: Seems like that is related to the **General** issue